# Using PyInstaller (console, onefile) on a .py file that includes statsmodels

Tags: python, pyinstaller, statsmodels

When I run the `.exe`, it generates the following in the console output:

> `C:\Python27\Scripts\dist>SNAPpy279.exe`
>
> `Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 26, in <module> File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module exec(bytecode, module.__dict__) File "C:\Python27\Scripts\build\SNAPpy279\out00-PYZ.pyz\statsmodels.api", line 19, in <module> File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module exec(bytecode, module.__dict__) File "C:\Python27\Scripts\build\SNAPpy279\out00-PYZ.pyz\statsmodels.__init__", line 8, in <module> ImportError: No module named tools.sm_exceptions`

Any potentially easy solutions for this?  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** Ran into this once again and my fix did not work. To solve it, I changed the line 
`from .tools.sm_exceptions import (ConvergenceWarning, CacheWriteWarning,
                                  IterationLimitWarning, InvalidTestWarning)`

In \statsmodels\__init__.py at line 8 to : 
`from statsmodels.tools.sm_exceptions import (ConvergenceWarning, CacheWriteWarning,
                                  IterationLimitWarning, InvalidTestWarning)`

---

I think I ran in the same issue last week. In my case, I fixed it by adding
`import statsmodels.api` 
in my main script.
The import was done within another module previously.

Hoping this helps.